# Return Type is Incompatible when implementing iterator

Tags: java

I am implementing iterator on a class and I keep getting the error for line 1 of the second part. It says that the return type is incompatible with iterator(). I know it has to do with the syntax of what I'm using since I'm new to coding.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Stack<Item> implements Iterable{
  private Item[] stack;
  private int size;
  private int N;

  public Stack(){
    stack = (Item[]) new Object[2];
    size = 0;
    N = 0;
  }

  public StackIterator<Item> iterator(){
    return new StackIterator<Item>();
  }

  public class StackIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item>{
```

Comment: There is an example of a working Iterator written up [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48109/simple-example-of-an-iterable-and-an-iterator-in-java).

Comment: Don't use raw types. `implements Iterable` should be `implements Iterable<Item>. You should prefer single-letter generic identifiers like E or T. Item looks like a real concrete class.